# Can't create BigQuery query jobs in Next.js project

Tags: next.js, google-bigquery, service-accounts

I'm a coop student working for a startup.

I'm writing my Next.js application and I need to fetch some data from the BigQuery. I've tried using ADC, service account, but I just can't create a simple query job. I can run the query job from command line using service account key, but my code won't work. The console logs would stop at 'Creating Query Job'. I've read all the documents I can possibly find.

Server side

```
export default async function fetchBigQuery(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    console.log('fetchBigQuery invoked::', req.method)

    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        res.status(405).end()  // Method not allowed
        return
    }

    const options = {
        keyFilename: '/path/to/service-acct.json',
        projectId: 'project-dev',
    }

    const bigquery = new BigQuery(options)

    const query = `SELECT * FROM alter-prime-dev.client_dmo_mar.out_dmo_mar_climate_hazards__assets LIMIT 10`

    console.log('did it get to here')

    try {
        console.log('Creating Query Job')
        const

 [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob({ query:query })
        console.log('Job Created:', job.id)

        console.log('Getting Query Results')
        const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults()
        console.log('Query Results:', rows)


        if (rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'No data found' })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ rows })  // Return the rows as a JSON response
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'BigQuery error' })
    }
}
```

front end

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const NamesComponent = () => {
    const [names, setNames] = useState<string[]>([])

    const queryBigQuery = async()=>{
        console.log('About to fetch data')  // Debugging line
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/api/fetchBigQuery', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            })

            if (res.ok) {
                const jsonData = await res.json()
                console.log('Fetched Data:', jsonData)  // Debugging line to view fetched data
                setNames(jsonData)  // Update the state with fetched data
            } else {
                console.error(`Error: ${res.status}`)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to fetch user data:', error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        queryBigQuery()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Fetched Data:</h1>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(names, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NamesComponent
```

I'm writing my next.js application and i need to fetch some data from the BigQuery... I think it's an authentication problem. I've tried using ADC (BigQuery User,Service Usage Consumer), service account (BigQuery UserService Usage Consumer),and give them all the permission I found necessary. But it just won't work, I get a 500 internal service error and that's it. I've tried the command line query and feeding the service account key directly as a parameter, that works. But when I try to do the same thing in the app, and I don't know if:

```
   const options = {
        keyFilename: '/Users/pinqiw/Desktop/WebStormProjects/prime-app/prime-initial-app/src/pages/api/alter-prime-dev-service-acct.json',
        projectId: 'alter-prime-dev',
    }

    const bigquery = new BigQuery(options)
```

actually allow my bigquery object to createQueryJob and getQueryResults. I'm not sure if it's using the service account key appropriately.